# User.pins is giving me error in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running into an error on Rails Console. When I type user.pins, I receive an error. Below is the text in the console that I get. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
2.1.2 :008 > user.pins
NoMethodError: undefined method pins' for #<User:0x007fa029493808>
from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activemodel-4.1.6/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:inmethod_missing'
from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:211:in method_missing'
from (irb):8
from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:instart'
from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in start'
from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:inconsole'
from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in run_command!'
from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in'
from bin/rails:8:in require'
from bin/rails:8:in'
```

Comment: What do you expect by calling `pins`? Provide more context.

Comment: I am trying to see or pull up the `pins` associated with that user.

Comment: Show your user model.

Comment: `class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_many :pins
end
`

Comment: Here is a link to a screen shot if easier.

http://imgur.com/MZi7Mbz

Comment: Did you `reload!` rails console after adding `has_many :pins`?

Comment: I just tried and I am still receiving a `NoMethodError: undefined method `pins' for #<User:0x007fa029493808>
`

Comment: Any other advice I can try?

Comment: Having of what you have should simply work. I mean `User.new.pins` should give you empty array and `User.last.pins` should returns some `Pin` objects if having any.